# WPF - Why would Loading image from relative path during runtime fail *unless* I examine the object in debugger?

Tags: wpf, image, uri, visual-studio-2019

Made a new test project just for this, with a button and an image.  MyImage.png is placed in the project's debug working directory, and NOT included in the project.

This works fine, with an absolute path specified:

```
private void BtnLoadFromFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri fileUri = new Uri("C:/blah/blah/blah/MyImage.png");
    BitmapImage myimage = new BitmapImage(fileUri);
    Imagebox.Source = myimage;
}
```

This does NOT show any image, with a relative path:

```
private void BtnLoadFromFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri fileUri = new Uri("MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
    BitmapImage myimage = new BitmapImage(fileUri);
    Imagebox.Source = myimage;
}
```

However, I noticed that the relative path DOES work if I set a breakpoint at the last line, examine myimage's properties (it holds data indicating MyImage.png was successfully found), then continue execution.  At which point the image shows up.  I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community.

I'm very confused why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug. A workaround would be to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`:

```
private void BtnLoadFromFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fileUri = new Uri("MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
    var myImage = new BitmapImage();
    myImage.BeginInit();
    myImage.UriSource = fileUri;
    myImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    myImage.EndInit();
    Imagebox.Source = myImage;
}
```

Or always use an absolute URI:

```
private void BtnLoadFromFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fileUri = new Uri(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "MyImage.jpg"));
    var myImage = new BitmapImage(fileUri);
    Imagebox.Source = myImage;
}
```